# How to do permissions right in Django

Tags: django, django-permissions

I have implmented a permissions system in django, but it is very basic and I think there might be better ways.

From my understanding permissions are labels that attach to certain users, then it is up to me what *actions* I associate with them. For example, `can_edit` is just a name for what action certain users can do, which will be decided by me later.

I used the command line to create a `can_edit` permission on a certain model,

```
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group, User, Permission

itmod_ct = ContentType.objects.get(app_label='myapp', model='mymodel')
can_modify = Permission(name='Can Modify', codename='can_modify_model', content_type=itmod_ct)
can_modify.save()
#some group of users g
g.permissions = (can_modify,)
g.save()
```

then in the template, I enforce it by enclosing associated functionality in

```
{% if perms.myapp.can_modify_model %}
... action that can be performed
{% endif %}
```

The primary problem with this approach is that suppose I now implement an API in the future, i.e something that performs the same action but without that template, then the app is as if there were no permissions/authorizations implemented as all. Another (philosophical) problem is using business logic in templates. Also, most of my views are common for all users except some things are editable a select few.

Answer (score 0):

re "a `can_edit` permission on a certain model" ...'add', 'change' and 'delete' permissions are auto created by Django for every model so this is possibly redundant

re doing this:

```
{% if perms.issuetracker.can_modify_itmod %}
... action that can be performed
{% endif %}
```

This is okay, *only because* this should not be the place where the permission is actually enforced. This is just some code to decide what option to show to the user.  The actual enforcement of the permission will occur in the view that processes the action.

It's rather up to you, but generally it is desirable to push the business logic all the way up into the models, as much as possible, though typically there is still much done at the view layer. You are correct that business logic should not be left to code in the template.